# Female astronaut travels through a wormhole and finds out that she's being pulled into a black hole

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi

I heard a short story (unfortunately not in English and without any title) as an audiobook, where the protagonist is a female astronaut Tessa Brunsack (or similarly named), who travels through wormholes regularly, using man-made portals, which travel through space.

Once, when flying together with a guy called DeLago (I don't remember his first name) they are injured, as they're flying much faster than expected, and find out subsequently that they're being pulled into a black hole. The short story was really cool, not only for being kinda science-heavy, but also for flashbacks of the protagonist's childhood describing the relationship with her father.

Do you know, what it could be?  I'm unable to find anything.

Comment: Do you recall what language you read it in?

Comment: Yeah, it was an audio in Czech (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwimcVf5ecA). The author of the YouTube channel is not communicating about it and I found out, that he's usually doing translations from other languages and just switching titles of the books...

Comment: It sounds a bit like Frederick Pohl's _Gateway_, seen from the other end. That's a full novel, though, not a short story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found it!

It's *Under the Graying Sea* by [Jonathan Sherwood](https://www.jonathansherwood.com) and it was first published in [Asimov's Science Fiction](https://www.asimovs.com/) in 2006.

The link to the short story in English is [here](http://bestsf.net/jonathan-sherwood-under-the-graying-sea/).

Also, the Czech translation I heard as an audiostory was published [in September 2011 in XB-1 magazine](http://www.casopisxb1.cz/obsahy/obsah-xb-1-92011/). The story in Czech is [here](https://tuzex.net/jonathan-sherwood-pod-sednoucim-morem-underthe-graying-sea/).